# "how to get the $ symbol from the below string xyz1abc$xyz2abc$"

Tags: sql-server

i need to get the $ symbol by using while loop

```
declare @str varchar(100) = 'xyz1abc$xyz2abc$'
declare @int int = charindex('$',@str)
while (@int > 0)
begin
  select @str = SUBSTRING(@str,@int,1)
  select @int = charindex('$',@str)
end

select @str
```

it is getting infinite loop

Comment: What do you mean "get the `$`"? The position? There's 2 in there, so so do you want both? You don't explain anything. Rather than telling us (nicely) to give you the answer, explain what your actual goal here is

Comment: What does *"get the `$` symbol"* mean here? You want to count how many there are? You want to return the `charindex()` of any instances of `$` int he string? You just want it to output every `$` it encounters? You want to remove any instance `$` from the string and return the result? It's not clear from your code or explanation.

Comment: I feel like, as the OP is trying to just return a `'$'` that the entire thing could be rewritten as `SELECT CASE WHEN @str LIKE '%$%' THEN '$' END;`

Answer (score 0):

the reason for the infinite loop is that @int begins and greater than 0 and then is never changed, so this condition is never false:

```
while (@int > 0)
```

I cannot be sure if the goal of your code is to find all $s and return their position or to find the second $, or something else.